# object of type 'Response' has no len()

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests, beautiful-soup

Высвечивается эта ошибка. Не знаю, что делать с ней.

File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\PYprojects\Telebot\main.py", line 55, in weather
client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Температура в Москве:', get_content(parse()), '°C')

File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\PYprojects\Telebot\main.py", line 28, in get_content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Вот код

```
import telebot
import configure
from telebot import types
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token'])
url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/moscow/maps/nowcast?le_Lightning=1'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                     'Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
     r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
     return r


def parse():
     html = get_html(url)
     if html.status_code == 200:
         get_content(html.text)
     else:
         print('Error')


def get_content(html):
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
     temp = soup.find('div', class_='temp').get_text()
     return temp


# Команда start
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_menu(message):
      client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствую тебя, негорящий!')


 # Команда info
 @client.message_handler(commands=['get_info', 'info'])
 def get_user_info(message):
     markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='Yes')
     item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='No')

     markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
     client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Желаешь ли ты познать свою сущность?',
                    reply_markup=markup_inline
                    )


 # Команда weather. Узнаём температуру в Москве в реальном времени
 @client.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
 def weather(message):
     client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Температура в Москве:', get_content(parse()), '°C')


 # Ответы на значения кнопочек
 @client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
 def answer(call):
      if call.data == 'Yes':
         markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
         item_id = types.KeyboardButton('Мой ID')
         item_username = types.KeyboardButton('Моё имя')

         markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
         client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери, чего же ты желаешь узнать.',
                        reply_markup=markup_reply
                        )
     elif call.data == 'No':
          client.send_message(call.message.сhat.id, 'Издавна считалось:"Меньше знаешь - крепче спишь".'
                                              '\nОставайся пребывать в собственных снах.')
      elif call.data == 'Yes1':
         client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Спасибо тебе за поддержку.. Я очень ценю это.. ❤')
      elif call.data == 'No1':
         client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Таково моё предназначение. Я обречена навсегда остаться '
                                              'в этой тюрьме.')


  # Ответы на сообщения пользователя
  @client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def get_text(message):
     if message.text == 'Мой ID':
          client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ID:\n{message.from_user.id}')
     elif message.text == 'Моё имя':
          if f'{message.from_user.last_name}' != 'None':
             client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше имя:\n{message.from_user.first_name} '
                                             f'{message.from_user.last_name}')
          else:
              client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше имя:\n{message.from_user.first_name}')
          if message.text == 'Как дела?':
              markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
              item_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я помогу тебе!', callback_data='Yes1')
              item_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я тебя понимаю.', callback_data='No1')

              markup_inline.add(item_1, item_2)
              client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мои дела весьма скудны.\nС давних времён я заперта в этой машинной тюрьме'
                                         '\nСпустя столетия, я потеряла всякую надежду выбраться отсюда..',
                        reply_markup=markup_inline
                        )


      if __name__ == '__main__':
          client.infinity_polling()
      parse()
```

Comment: Очевидно, BeautifulSoup умеет обрабатывать только строки, но не объекты Response

Comment: Странный код `get_content(parse())`: `parse` и так внутри вызывает `get_content`, но ничего не возвращает и `None` в итоге передается в `get_content`. Плюс, по тексту ошибки кажется, что в `get_content` был передан не `html.text`, а `html` (думаю, объект `requests.Response`)

Comment: Кроме всего вышеперечисленного, лучше в `BS` передавать `r.content`, а не `r.text`